# Using \o command within a script

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Is there a way I can use the \o command from with in psycopg2. If not, is there any way I can automate this command. I am trying to include this command in a script and am not sure how to do it. I need the file  to be in the same format as output by the \o command, so I cannot use the \copy command.

Comment: `\o` is a psql command. You can't do it with psycopg. You just get your result set and format it before saving to the file.

Comment: Is there a way I can send the \o command using psql? Say, the -c option of psql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just discovered a way to put the '\o' command in a script as was mentioned in the postgres [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-psql.html). All you need to do is, pipe these "meta commands" to psql. Here's how to do it:

```
echo "\o test.out \\ select * from test;" | psql -wU user db_name
```